# How can I invoke a POJO using WAS scheduler(websphere Scheduler)?

Tags: java, websphere

In Webpshere application server how to create schedulers?
And thru was schedulers how to invoke simple java class?

Comment: Is there a specific WAS Version that you are looking at? Using the newer versions might possibly present additional options.

Answer (score 2):

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc%2Finfo%2Fae%2Fscheduler%2Ftasks%2Ftsch_ep.html

Answer (score 1):

Don't think you can run a POJO directly.
As far as I know, schedulers can only be used to run Enterprise JavaBean methods or send Java Message Service messages using any J2EE server application.

Basic steps

- create a scheduler using admin console
- create EJB to execute the task you want to run using the scheduler
- create another EJB/servlet etc to manage the task - register, start,suspend,resume etc the task in the scheduler

Check this out https://seenukarthi.com/websphere/2010/05/31/sheduling-job-in-websphere-appserver-6/